# How to validate token in azuredevops extension using nodejs

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, web-applications, jwt

I followed the official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/auth?view=azure-devops

in document they are giving examples in .net, i want to validate token using nodejs

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const token =
  "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiI5MGJjZWM3Yy0wNWRkLTZjMWMtOWU2Mi1iOTA1NDhjYzZiYjgiLCJ0aWQiOiJXaW5kb3dzIExpdmUgSUQiLCJpc3MiOiJhcHAudnN0b2tlbi52aXN1YWxzdHVkaW8uY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiZGM5MjBhZDEtMmIxMC00OTNhLWI2OWItYzBkODZhNTViNWNiIiwibmJmIjoxNjQ2OTA3MjYyLCJleHAiOjE2NDY5MTE0NjJ9.wi45NQB72U0z_SST84lEFOAdcke-WD_WNJDWulW69Ds";

const secret =
  "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im9PdmN6NU1fN3AtSGpJS2xGWHo5M3VfVjBabyJ9.eyJjaWQiOiJhNjMyMjhlOS0xNTdmLTRjNDMtOTFjOC03YjA1MTU4ODk3YTUiLCJjc2kiOiI0YmU5NTdjMy0yNzcxLTQxMzktYmY0Yi03YzAxMDZhYTFjNDAiLCJuYW1laWQiOiIwMDAwMDAyOS0wMDAwLTg4ODgtODAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJpc3MiOiJhcHAudnN0b2tlbi52aXN1YWxzdHVkaW8uY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBwLnZzdG9rZW4udmlzdWFsc3R1ZGlvLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTY0NTA4OTgyNiwiZXhwIjoxODAyODU2MjI2fQ.VvLnhea2bZ8kV8A8FiMPhUqkuteP7IGWnQJNdeLrsdpsLGn1iDMfMEUatWVNjDJjBUbOAx7p3o1QEc-S7iF6VhllhJIyuFtd-dh0M98uR9K-D2kHOUKI_HG_ckcHqyEmXXx9w8fBfQKoH1dXi2aDQZbjjbE3pLLmU3ZuuZtnOF8KFjQL0yk-J1oPJH2gPz83NMzyscCwKwj5SRJN0RyNV40FQpQ0ps91oG_5PMOHwlgEzchLimFsoY82ixY1EzfOcLqEInLNsw5b23dqmYgThz_6A60hC9fGc43pPEJQECST3Lv-BqAmzGL9WPXGgXxJ69OXZeVJ_Mi8FOYPHiDhuQ";

jwt.verify(token, secret, { algorithms: ["HS256"] }, function (err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(decoded);
  }
});
```

ERROR: JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature

Comment: Are you looking to decode the token and access the claims, or check if the token is valid?

Comment: I want check token is valid or not

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please try the methods and if you need any help, we are willing to help you.

Comment: I converted secret format to base64. still it is not working